# Unable to perform data binding inside stepper component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have 2 input fields called `Course name`(Autocomplete component) and `Price`(input component):
On selecting particular `Course name`,the `price` was displaying according to the `Course name` like this:

[image]

Now, I have placed these two input fields **(i,e course name and price)** inside **stepper component**.Then data binding is not happening(i,e on selecting `course name` i am unable to display the `price` ).

Here is the stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dv4jcj-uyjzsd?file=app/stepper-overview-example.ts)

Comment: Why are `matPrice`, `phyPrice`, and `chemPrice` string arrays?

Comment: sorry i didn't changed the code while posting in **stackblitz**

Comment: Now i have updated the **stackblitz**...:) @SiddAjmera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. You should use the `name` attribute if you're using `[(ngModel)]`. But you haven't used it.
2. There's an issue with this implementation:

---

```
this.offeringControl.valueChanges.subscribe((d) => {
  console.log('Changed');
  console.log('d: ', d);
  if (d === 'CCNA Training') {
      this.price = this.matPrice;
    } else if (d === 'Java Coaching') {
      this.price = this.phyPrice;
    } else if  (d === 'PHP Training') {
      this.price = this.chemPrice;
    }
  });
```

Here, the strings `CCNA Training`, `Java Coaching`, and `PHP Training` should be, `Maths`, `Physics`, and `chemistry`.

As your AutoComplete only has Maths, Physics, and chemistry.

Here's a [**fixed and Updated StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dv4jcj-nk7gyb?file=app/stepper-overview-example.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for guidance..:)